# How can i read this src text with selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium

```
<iframe id="frameNewAnimeuploads0" src="http://www.watchcartoononline.com/inc/animeuploads/embed.php?file=rick%20and%20morty%2FRick.and.Morty.S02E10.The.Wedding.Squanchers.720p.WEB-DL.DD5.1.flv&amp;hd=1" width="530" height="410" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

I want to read src text.
(http://www.watchcartoononline.com/inc/animeuploads/embed.php?file=rick%20and%20morty%2FRick.and.Morty.S02E10.The.Wedding.Squanchers.720p.WEB-DL.DD5.1.flv&hd=1)

How can i read this ?

Comment: What do you mean by "read"? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @alexanderbird example: a = src.text and browser.get(a). Then i go another website and i will read next src text and i will go new src site. But i don't know how can i read src text with selenium.

Comment: i tried this : kod = '<iframe id="frameNewAnimeuploads0" src="(.+?)" width="530" height="410" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>'
comb = re.compile(kod)
htmlkod = tarayici.page_source
titles = re.findall(comb, htmlkod)
but i couldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do it. Firs you need to identify the `frame` which is a `WebElement` and then you can get its `Attribute` using getAttribute method.

```
frame = driver.find_element_by_id('frameNewAnimeuploads0')
frame.get_attribute("src")
```

Hope it helps!